Can not save in mongodb using spring cloud with kafka
Have a problem saving in Mongodb using stream cloud with Kafka.
If I create a new resource (POST) from Swagger, the code works correctly, that is, it first saves the corresponding document in Mongodb and then creates the corresponding message in Kafka.
But since I have the same topic for the producer and subscriber, the code also reads the Kafka message (handleEvent method) and calls my service again, but by having a boolean controlling in the method if it comes from Kafka or not, it does not resubmit to kafka.
The problem is that it does not save in Mongodb again either (even though it is the same entity, I have also tried to create another one hot and it does not save it).
A similar case happens to me when, from outside the application, I use the producer from the console (CMD) and create the corresponding JSON. The code goes directly to handleEvent and invokes the service, but it never saves to Mongodb, I can't debug there.
The problem could come from the security context? If I do it from the console, am I skipping that context and that's why it doesn't save? I have created a defaultIfEmpty to fill in the username attribute indicating that it comes from kafka but it has not worked for me, I don't know what the problem is and why my code when invoked from Kafka (instead of from swagger) is not able to save the entity in Mongodb. I have also checked that the entity is filled correctly, and it is, except for the creationUser field, which sets it to null
This is my Service class:
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    private static final EntityMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper(EntityMapper.class);

    private final Repository repository;

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, Event> kafkaTemplate;

    ServiceImpl(Repository repository, KafkaTemplate<String, Event> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    public Mono<ReqDTO> createEntity(UUID id, ReqDTO dto, boolean fromKafka) {
        Mono<String> userName = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(ctx -> 
    ctx.getAuthentication().getName())
                .doOnError(error -> log.error("Error retrieving user from security context: {}", 
    error.getMessage()))
                .defaultIfEmpty("KAFKA");

        var entity = mapper.mapToEntity(dto);
        return userName.doOnNext(name -> {
            entity.setCreationUser(name);
        }).doOnError(error -> log.error("Error retrieving user from security context: {}", 
    error.getMessage()))
                .then(repository.save(entity).flatMap(savedEntity -> {
                    if (!fromKafka) {
                        Event event = new Event(savedEntity.getId());
                        sendToKafka(Event);
                    }
                    return Mono.just(mapper.mapToReqDTO(savedEntity));
                })
        );
    }

    private void sendToKafka(Event event) {
        kafkaTemplate.send("channel", event);
    }
}

There is my subscriber class
@Component
public class Subscriber {

    @Value("${spring.cloud.stream.bindings.events.destination}")
    public String topic;

    @Value("${spring.cloud.stream.bindings.events-in-0.group}")
    public String groupId;

    private Service Service;

    private static final Mapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper(Mapper.class);

    public Subscriber(Service service) {
        this.Service = service;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "#{__listener.topic}", groupId = "#{__listener.groupId}")
    public void handleEvent(@Payload String message) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Event dto = null;
        ReqDTO reqDTO = null;
        try {
            dto = objectMapper.readValue(message, event.class);
            reqDTO = mapper.mapToDTO(dto);
            service.createEntity(dto.getId(), reqDTO, true);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}

